# Strange delay / freeze after GET request with status 200 only on Firefox 61.0.1

Tags: firefox

Please take a look at screen from Network Monitor. This strange behaviour only happens on Firefox, it works fine on Chrome, Safari - no delay / freeze. Any ideas what could possibly happen there will be helpful.

I noticed also that delay is much shorter when I used older version of Firefox 56.0.

[Screen form Network Monitor](https://monosnap.com/file/95biFBcN2axuajubOffVDRskcJpXVw)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the problem was regular expression in JS file that we used to check if string is URL. It worked super slow on Firefox. We updated it to something else and it's fine now.